# Issue with converting timestamp to seconds

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

Basically what I'm trying to do is to convert mysql timestamp to "xx seconds ago" format. I use this function - $age = time() - strtotime($eventTime). I get the result, but it shows time in seconds 1 one hour later (-3600s). E.G. If I posted right now, it'd show (-3600s ago). What's the problem it could be?

Comment: can't say much without looking at your data, it can be because where u generated $eventTime has a 1 hour gap from the server you checked `time()`

Comment: Well, I'm using local hosting. I wonder maybe where are any times zones settings or smth?

Comment: how do you create the value for `$eventTime`

Comment: timezones shouldnt matter because both those functions should give seconds in UTC/GMT. So are you saying that no matter what the `$age` is greater than 3600?

Comment: $eventTime = $row['time'] and 'time' is timestap when the record to a table was made.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your MySQL session and your PHP settings are both sharing the same timezone, you could use something like this to get a suitable time period in English:

```
function toFriendlyTime($seconds) {
    // Used in the item view, this function returns a 'friendly', rough-idea type time, like "3 hours" or "4 months"
    $measures = array(
        'month'=>30*24*60*60,
        'week'=>7*24*60*60,
        'day'=>24*60*60,
        'hour'=>60*60,
        'minute'=>60,
        'second'=>1,
    );
    foreach ($measures as $label=>$amount) {
        if ($seconds >= $amount) {
            $howMany = floor($seconds / $amount);
            return $howMany." ".$label.($howMany > 1 ? "s" : "");
        }
    }
    return "1 second";
}
```